# Idealized trajectory from sloped surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile

I am a [GIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system) programmer implementing a visualization.

I am modeling the idealized trajectory of a particle ejected from a volcanic vent using:

$$\text{distance} = \frac{(v^2 \times  sin(2\theta))}{g}.$$

Where $g = 1.62\:\mathrm{m/s^2}$, $v$ is velocity, and $\theta$ is ejection angle. $g$ is the lunar gravity constant I was supplied.

How can I incorporate the slope of the underlying surface assuming a single point of ejection?        $$$$$$$$

EDIT:
My current workflow is to compute total travel distance, extract a topographic profile along the total theoretical travel distance and then check the height of the projectile to the height of the actual surface at 100m intervals.  In this way I can compute the landing site for the projectile.

EDIT 2: 
I updated the question with the correct formula.  Apologies for the incorrect transposition.  My implementation now assumes a completely flat surface.  What happens when the ejection surface is sloped either uphill or downhill?

Comment: If you want to know the trajectory, what you are interested should be x(t) and y(t) instead of distance. Also what is the meaning of the last questions? n points is no different from a single point. Can you clarify that

Comment: One more things, your equation looks wrong and g, how do you get this?

Comment: @Jay Laura Firstly, your formula is still wrong. $\frac{v^2\sin2\theta}{g}\neq\frac{2v^2\sin\theta}{g}$ Secondly, I've updated my answer with a formula that might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idealized projectile launched from ground with speed $v$ at angle $\theta$ measured from zenith will reach ground at time:

$$
t=\frac{2v\sin\theta}{g}
$$

assuming the ground is level. The horizontal distance it will have traveled in that time is:

$$
d=\frac{2v^2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{g}=\frac{v^2\sin 2\theta}{g}
$$

For small $\theta$ you could approximate this with:

$$
d\approx\frac{2v^2\theta}{g}
$$

but I guess you need a formula that works also for larger $\theta$.

If the ground is sloped with a constant angle $\alpha$ (positive angles for uphill slopes) from the ejection point to where it hits the ground, you can use the following formula:

$$
d=\frac{2v^2\sin\theta(\cos\theta-\sin\theta\tan\alpha)}{g}
$$

Do you want me to show you how I derived the formula?

Comment: I updated my question to hopefully include more information.  Apologies for an incomplete question. Quite out of my element!

Comment: Thanks.  I would be interested in knowing how the derivation works.  Again, not a physicist, but interested.